# Solaris11: Alternative to xVM Hypervisor?

Tags: solaris, virtual-machine, virtualization

AFAIK, support for the xVM Hypervisor - basically Xen - has been dropped in Solaris 11.  Is there an alternative/replacement for it?  How does it compare to Xen?

Obviously there is zones if you want to run Solaris, and there is VirtualBox if you want a virtual computer in a separate program. But is there anything similar to Hypervisor/Xen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For running Solaris in dom0, no. Oracle has euthanized it. xVM worked on Solaris 10 but it broke during the development cycle of OpenSolaris (it's completely broken and unusable on snv_134, but probably earlier). Neither Oracle nor the Illumos community has shown any interest in getting a Solaris kernel running in dom0.

Oracle's replacement product is OracleVM. On Sparc that means Solaris LDOMs. On x86 that means Xen with Oracle Linux in dom0.

In the Illumos community, Joyent has ported Linux's KVM to the Illumos kernel. It's available at least from SmartOS, but I believe it's also available in OpenIndiana and OmniOS**.

If you want **Xen** I suggest Debian. If you want **ZFS*** I suggest OmniOS or SmartOS and use KVM.

---

* FreeBSD [still can't run dom0](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/Xen#Setup).
** As years have passed, KVM is available in most, if not all illumos distributions and Joyent has resurrected LX-brand zones as part of SmartOS and are now also in OmniOS.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on the hardware.

With UltraSPARC T based servers, you can use [Oracle VM Server for SPARC](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/oraclevm/Oracle+VM+Server+for+SPARC), a.k.a LDOMs.

On x86 based ones, [Oracle VM Server for x86](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/oraclevm/overview/index.html) supports Solaris 11 as a guest although the server and manager are based on Oracle Linux, not Oracle Solaris 11.

For the record, a KVM module has been [ported to the Illumos kernel](http://dtrace.org/blogs/bmc/2011/08/15/kvm-on-illumos/) (OpenSolaris fork).